# NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver and a custom NSArray subclass unarchives to a different subclass

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I have a subclass of `NSMutableArray` (necessary to enforce certain restrictions on the contained objects). I encode the array as usual, and then decode it. The problem is that while the encoded class (given to `NSKeyedArchiver`) is a `JOTypedMutableArray`, the output class is another subclass of `NSMutableArray` (one of the private ones).

I looked into the archived data with LLDB: `po [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:archivedData mutabilityOption:0 format:NULL errorDescription:NULL]`. The output of that command contained this:

```
"$classes" = (
    NSMutableArray,
    NSArray,
    NSObject
);
"$classname" = NSMutableArray;
```

It appears to me that while the archiver is given a subclass of the class cluster, it is set to ignore the concrete subclasses and encode as the abstract superclass.

The question here is: how could I force the archiver to encode the object correctly? (Or am I doing something else wrong here?)

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString *stringType = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"JOTypedMutableArrayType"];
        Class classType = NSClassFromString(stringType);
        _type = classType;

        NSMutableArray *backingArray = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"JOTypedMutableArrayContents"];
        _jo_backingArray = backingArray;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:NSStringFromClass(self.type) forKey:@"JOTypedMutableArrayType"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.jo_backingArray forKey:@"JOTypedMutableArrayContents"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you encode using the property-list serialization you're restricting yourself to the basic property-list types: array, string, dictionary, data, some others I forget right now...[docs are here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

This is a "feature" of NSPropertyListSerialization , because property-lists are textual and don't contain explicit type information. If you want to include all the type information you'll need to use a different class of archiver, check NSArchiver.

From what little I know of your case, though, I might recommend just changing the array back to the type you want when you read it in, so you can continue to use the nice text format.

Like, you could do:

```
NSMutableArray *backingArray = [JOTypedMutableArray arrayWithArray:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"JOTypedMutableArrayContents"]];
```

Comment: I am using `NSKeyedArchiver`. "NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver" is the first thing in the title of my question, and I gave my implementations of `-initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`. I'm well aware that `NSPropertyListSerialization` does not store type info, but I also know that `NSKeyedArchiver` writes a property list. I only used `NSPropertyListSerialization` to see what exactly the encoder was encoding, and the issue is that the `NSKeyedArchiver` is not storing the correct type information.

Comment: I would believe class clusters archive strangely. The code snippet I provide above will work around this. In general I strongly STRONGLY recommend against subclassing clusters like NSArray, for a huge number of reasons like this.